# How to achieve the following in Cypher query?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I tried the following query @ http://goo.gl/Ou2GZG

```
START s=node(1), t=node(4)
MATCH p=s-[*]-pt--t
WHERE SINGLE (n1 IN nodes(p) 
              WHERE id(n1)=id(t))
WITH DISTINCT pt AS pts, t
MATCH p=t-[*]-pfn
WHERE NONE (n IN nodes(p) 
            WHERE id(n)=3 OR id(n)=7)
RETURN DISTINCT pfn AS pf
```

but I don't want to hard code 3 and 7 in the penultimate line where 3 and 7 are the nodes contained in (pts). I tried the following but I am getting "Unclosed parenthesis" error

```
START s=node(1), t=node(4) 
MATCH p=s-[*]-pt--t 
WHERE SINGLE (n1 IN nodes(p) 
              WHERE id(n1)=id(t)) 
WITH DISTINCT pt AS pts, t 
MATCH p=t-[*]-pfn FOREACH(pt in pts : 
                          WHERE NONE (n IN nodes(p) 
                                      WHERE id(n)=id(pt))) 
RETURN DISTINCT pfn AS pf
```

Comment: I don't understand how the data at the link you included has anything to do with your question? [edit] in the url from the 'share' link once you get your sample data loaded there.

Comment: Please [edit] relevant information into the question itself... it is very hard to read right now.

Comment: @Dinesh - Please remove all of these comments and edit your question. As it stands, this question is spread across the question plus 8 comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use the ALL predicate to ensures that for each node n in the path p there doesn't exist a node in pt that has the same id as the node n,

```
START s=node(1), t=node(4) 
MATCH p=s-[*]-pt--t 
WHERE SINGLE (n1 IN nodes(p) 
              WHERE id(n1)=id(t)) 
WITH DISTINCT collect(id(pt)) AS pts, t 
MATCH p=t-[*]-pfn 
WHERE ALL (n IN nodes(p) 
           WHERE NONE (pt IN pts 
                       WHERE id(n)= pt)) 
RETURN DISTINCT pfn AS pf
```

Comment: that works great. but I would like to know why I am getting "Unclosed parenthesis" error on my 2nd query.

Comment: I think the "Foreach" is a writing command, within its parentheses, one of the writing commands such as "Set", "Create", "Delete" etc is expected.